# Websocket Permessage-deflate not occuring in server -> client direction

Tags: python, websocket, permessagedeflate

I have written my own implementation of a websocket in python to teach myself their inner workings. I was going to be sending large repetitive JSON objects over the websocket so I am trying to implement `permessage-deflate`. The compression works in the `client->server` direction, but not in the  `server -> client` direction

This is the header exchange:

**Request**

```
Host: awebsite.com:port
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://awebsite.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: JItmF32mfGXXKYyhcEoW/A==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

**Response**

```
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: zYQKJ6gvwlTU/j2xw1Kf0BErg9c=
```

When I do this, I get compressed data from the client as expected and it inflates as expected.

When I send an uncompressed message, I get a normal response on the client, Ie i send "hello" and I get "hello"

When I try to deflate my message using this simple python function:

```
def deflate(self,data,B64_encode=False):
   data=zlib.compress(data)
   if B64_encode:
       return base64.b64encode(data[2:-4])
   else:
       return data[2:-4]
```

I get an error message about the characters not being utf-8, and when I base64 encode the compressed message, I just get the base64 encoded string.  I also tried sending the data as Binary over the websocket, and get a blob at the other end.  I've been scouring the internet for a while now and haven't heard of this happening.  My Guess is that I am compressing the data at the wrong step.  Below is the function I use to send the data.  So far I've been feeding in the compressed message into the `send()` function because from what I've read permessage compression happens on the message level, and all the other data remains uncompressed.

```
def send(self, string, TYPE="TEXT"):
                import struct
                conn = self.conn
                datatypes = {
                        "TEXT": 0x01,
                        "BINARY": 0x02,
                        "CLOSE": 0X08,
                        "PING": 0x09,
                        "PONG": 0x0A}
                b1 = 0x80
                b2 = 0
                message = ""
                if TYPE == "TEXT":
                        if type(string) == unicode:
                                b1 |= datatypes["TEXT"]
                                payload = string.encode("UTF8")
                        elif type(string) == str:
                                b1 |= datatypes["TEXT"]
                                payload = string
                                message += chr(b1)
                else:
                        b1 |= datatypes[TYPE]
                        payload = string
                        message += chr(b1)
                length = len(payload)
                if length < 126:
                        b2 |= length
                        message += chr(b2)
                elif length < (2 ** 16) - 1:
                        b2 |= 126
                        message += chr(b2)
                        l = struct.pack(">H", length)
                        message += l
                else:
                        l = struct.pack(">Q", length)
                        b2 |= 127
                        message += chr(b2)
                        message += l
                message += payload
                try:
                        conn.send(str(message))
                except socket.error:
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        conn.close()
                if TYPE == "CLOSE":
                        self.Die = True
                        conn.shutdown(2)
                        conn.close()
                        print self.myid,"Closed"
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of sleuthing, I found out my problem was a case of "RTFM".  In the third paragraph of (a?) [the manua](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-permessage-compression-19)l on perMessage Compression it says

> A WebSocket client may offer multiple PMCEs during the WebSocket
> opening handshake.  A peer WebSocket server received those offers may
> choose and accept preferred one or decline all of them.  PMCEs use
> the RSV1 bit of the WebSocket frame header to indicate whether a
> message is compressed or not, so that an endpoint can choose not to
> compress messages with incompressible contents.

I didn't know what the rsv bits did when I first set this up, and had them set to 0 by default.  My code now allows for compression to be set in the `send()` function in my program.  It nicely shrinks my messages from 30200 bytes to 149 bytes.

My Modified code now looks like this:

```
        def deflate2(self,data):
            data=zlib.compress(data)
            data=data[2:-4]
            return data

        def send(self, string, TYPE="TEXT",deflate=False):
                import struct
                if (deflate):
                    string=self.deflate(string)
                conn = self.conn
                datatypes = {
                        "TEXT": 0x01,
                        "BINARY": 0x02,
                        "CLOSE": 0X08,
                        "PING": 0x09,
                        "PONG": 0x0A}
                b1 = 0x80              #0b100000000
                if(deflate): b1=0xC0   #0b110000000 sets RSV1 to 1 for compression
                b2 = 0
                message = ""
                if TYPE == "TEXT":
                        if type(string) == unicode:
                                b1 |= datatypes["TEXT"]
                                payload = string.encode("UTF8")
                        elif type(string) == str:
                                b1 |= datatypes["TEXT"]
                                payload = string
                                message += chr(b1)
                else:
                        b1 |= datatypes[TYPE]
                        payload = string
                        message += chr(b1)
                length = len(payload)
                if length < 126:
                        b2 |= length
                        message += chr(b2)
                elif length < (2 ** 16) - 1:
                        b2 |= 126
                        message += chr(b2)
                        l = struct.pack(">H", length)
                        message += l
                else:
                        l = struct.pack(">Q", length)
                        b2 |= 127
                        message += chr(b2)
                        message += l
                message += payload
                try:
                        if self.debug:
                            for x in message: print("S>: ",x,hex(ord(x)),ord(x))
                        conn.send(str(message))
                except socket.error:
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        conn.close()
                if TYPE == "CLOSE":
                        self.Die = True
                        conn.shutdown(2)
                        conn.close()
                        print self.myid,"Closed"
```